# Unable to get access token in Facebook Graph Explorer

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

When I connect to Facebook Graph Explorer :

```
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/145634995501895
```

I click in "Get Access Token", if I check a permission, I receive the error :

```
"Sorry, this feature isn't available right now: An error occurred while processing this request. Please try again later."
```

I tried since another computer and same issue.
But, yesterday, it was working and I got one token and I was able to run some queries, but now it seems I got like "blocked" by Facebook.

How to fix that?

Screenshot : [image]

Thanks

Comment: What permissions did you ask for when the error occurred?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally the issue got resolved by itself, I just waited a couple of weeks.